# Rails 4 - Couldn't find Subscription with 'id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

**Question**: Could one kindly advise me how i adjust my method to relate to the url in order to avoid the `error Couldn't find Subscription with 'id'=`, depending on which payment option the user selects & the displayed url - i will explain much clearer below:

- I have 2 urls
- **[option payment 1]** when a user chooses the option to pay to attend an event, the user is directed to the payment new page and this url appears: `http://localhost:3000/payments/new?event_id=2&user=4`
- **[option payment 2]** when a user chooses the subscription option, the user is directed to the payment new page and this url appears: `http://localhost:3000/payments/new?subcription_id=1&user=4`

in my `payments_controller.rb` file for the action `new` i have the below method:

```
def new
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:subcription_id])
    @subcription_id = params[:subcription_id]
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @event_id = params[:event_id]
    @payment = Payment.new
  end
```

when a user chooses **[option payment 1]** and is directed to the payment new page with the displaying url `http://localhost:3000/payments/new?event_id=2&user=4` i get the below error

```
Couldn't find Subscription with 'id'=
```

> Question:

Could one kindly advise me how i adjust my method to relate to the url inorder to avoid the error `Couldn't find Subscription with 'id'=`, depending on which payment option the user selects & the displayed url

**i tried the below but no luck:**

```
def new
    if @subscription.present?
      @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:subcription_id])
      @subcription_id = params[:subcription_id]
    elsif @event.present?
      @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
      @event_id = params[:event_id]
    end
    @payment = Payment.new
  end
```

i also tried this but no luck:

```
def new
    if is_path?("/payments/new?subcription_id=1&user=4")
      @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:subcription_id])
      @subcription_id = params[:subcription_id]
    elsif is_path?("/payments/new?event_id=2&user=4")
      @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
      @event_id = params[:event_id]
    end
    @payment = Payment.new
  end

def is_path?(*paths)
    paths.include?(request.path)
  end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below worked for me:

```
def new
    @subcription_id = params[:subcription_id]
    @event_id = params[:event_id]
    @payment = Payment.new
    if @subcription_id.present?
      @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:subcription_id])
    elsif @event_id.present?
     @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make the finds conditional on whether the parameter is present.

```
def new
  @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:subcription_id]) if params[:subscription_id].present?
  @subcription_id = params[:subcription_id]
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id]) if params[:event_id].present?
  @event_id = params[:event_id]
  @payment = Payment.new
end
```

or perhaps more clearly...

```
def new
  if params[:subscription_id].present?
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:subcription_id])
    @subcription_id = params[:subcription_id]
  end
  if params[:event_id].present?
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id]) 
    @event_id = params[:event_id]
  end
  @payment = Payment.new
end
```

Comment: i don't think this works - when i try and access the code `<%= @subscription.title %>` in the views/payments/_form.html.erb i get the error `undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass` i have attached an image of this error

Comment: If you think there might be trouble with something like this you can use `try` which will at least not raise an error. `<%= @subscription.try(:title) %>`.

Comment: You should do as @Dan says... if on the new record you have no `@subscription` (because you didn't pass a `params[:subscription_id]`) then how can you expect `@subscription.title` to work?   Doing `@subscription.try(:title)` (or `@subscription&.title` with Ruby version 2.3) will return `nil` for `title` if `@subscription` is nil.